# AAPT: error: attribute startIconDrawable not found

Tags: java, xml, android-studio

I have an error:
C: \ Users \ juan_ \ AndroidStudioProjects \ DermaApp \ app \ src \ main \ res \ layout \ activity_login.xml: 33: AAPT: error: attribute startIconDrawable (aka com.example.example: startIconDrawable) not found.

The error is in this line of the XML :        app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_email"

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textinputlayoutCorreo"
        app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_email"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="299dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:hint="Correo"
        android:textColor="@color/colorNegro"
        app:counterEnabled="true"
        app:counterMaxLength="30"
        app:helperText="Requerido"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textinputlayoutContrasena"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextcorreo"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="54dp"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:textColor="@color/colorNegro"
            android:maxLength="30"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update Material design library to the latest version in build.Gradle(Module:App) file
i.e

`implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-rc01'`

Answer (score 0):

Better use the latest **stable** version - than a release candidate:

```
implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1"
```

Anything later than `1.1.0-alpha05` should work, as it had been added [there](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/commit/2642ff2697899791682b1556bb0ea774bd06592f#diff-f9daefe114434ebc5a06997bc6386a9df2496cd2c05e057905fa40e4eea9717aR56).

Answer (score 0):

remove the attribute `app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_email"`

then your code will be like:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textinputlayoutCorreo"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="299dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:hint="Correo"
        android:textColor="@color/colorNegro"
        app:counterEnabled="true"
        app:counterMaxLength="30"
        app:helperText="Requerido"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textinputlayoutContrasena"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextcorreo"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="54dp"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:textColor="@color/colorNegro"
            android:maxLength="30"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

then the error will gone